# 4500 cisco to dell 3516 input errors

Tags: cisco

I have a cisco 4500 switch that has a direct connection to a dell 3516 blade switch. I am getting a large number of input errors. I have tried new cables and still continue to see the errors.

Comment: Did you want to be more specific as to what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Do the auto-negotiate settings match on each side?

On the Cisco set "speed auto" and "duplex auto" on the interface and do the same on the Dell switch OR (and preferably not) fix speed and duplex on both sides.